# Creating a teams tab application within Angular

Tags: angular, microsoft-teams

I am trying to create a Teams App which will have a custom tab. I have added my standalone Angular app as a Tab.But I want to bring in Teams Context into my app by adding Teams Client SDK.

With the Yeoman Generator, I get the app scaffold with React components.

Is there any way we could create an App with Angular instead or is there any sample Angular app?

I tried to add the Teams initialization in my Angular App Component, but it still doesn't give me any info.

```
ngOnInit() {

    microsoftTeams.initialize();
    microsoftTeams.getContext(function(Context: microsoftTeams.Context) {
     this.teamName = Context.teamName;
     this.groupID = Context.groupId;
      this.teamID = Context.teamId;
});
```

Comment: Did you uploaded your app package in Teams and than tried? Could you please provide your manifest?

Comment: Hi, Yes I tried adding the package to Teams but still no luck. The manifest file validation is successful and there are no errors in it. Is there anything specific attribute to look out ?

Comment: Nothing much, If you added the teams client sdk in your app, you should able to get the context for your tab once you sideload the app package in teams. could you please try to get the context in constructor itself?

Comment: Is there any documentation or working sample with this scenario ?

Comment: There is no documentation available for angular but i'm sure you can fetch the context in angular app just try to fetch the context in constructor.

Comment: I am still stuck with login authentication.Does anyone have any docs to refer to?